# The closed form of this zeta-type function for all $N\ge 0\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-zeta

In [F.M.S. Lima's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0910.5004.pdf) on Riemann zeta-type functions, he conjectures the following formula:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\zeta(2n)}{2n(2n+1)\dots(2n+N)}\frac{1}{4^n}}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\ln{\pi}}{N!}-\frac{H_N}{N!}+\sum_{m=1}^{(N-1)/2}(-1)^{m+1}\frac{\zeta(2m+1)}{\pi^{2m}(N-2m)!}\right]$$
For $N$ being a positive odd integer.

Assuming this is true, I feel that this can be extended to any positive integer $N$.

All I am going on is the fact that for $N=2$ we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\zeta(2n)}{2n(2n+1)(2n+2)}\frac{1}{4^n}}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\ln{\pi}}{2!}-\frac{H_2}{2!}+\frac{7}{4\pi^2}\zeta(3)\right]$$
According to WolframAlpha.

But sums like the following don't make any sense
$$\frac{7}{4\pi^2}\zeta(3)=\sum_{m=1}^{1/2}(-1)^{m+1}\frac{\zeta(2m+1)}{\pi^{2m}(2-2m)!}$$

Then what is the generalized definition for the zeta sum for any $N\ge 0\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Euler-Maclaurin summation formula could help make sense of some fractional summations.

Comment: I think the simplest good start for fractional summations to analyze would be the fractional harmonic numbers.

Comment: What ? ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: I think the analogous conjecture to F.M.S. Lima's linked to above, but instead for even $N\ge 2$ is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\frac{\zeta(2n)}{2n(2n+1)\dots(2n+N)}\frac{1}{4^n}}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\ln{\pi}}{N!}-\frac{H_N}{N!}+\sum_{m=1}^{(N-2)/2}(-1)^{m+1}\frac{\zeta(2m+1)}{\pi^{2m}(N-2m)!}+(-1)^{(N/2)+1}\left(\frac{2^{N+1}-1}{2^{N+1}}\right){\frac{{2}\zeta(N+1)}{\pi^{N}}}\right]$$

When $N=0$ the sum equals $[ln({\pi/2})/2]$ and when $N=1$ the sum equals the first two terms of Lima's conjectural formula. These first two results are widely known and easily proved (e.g. see Boros and Moll, Irresistible Integrals)

Answer (score 0):

Let me just tell you that my conjecture, mentioned above, has been proved true (by myself) in Theorem 2 of:  Annali di Matematica Pura ed Applicata vol.194, p.1015 (2015).  There in Theorem 3 of this paper, I prove a generalization of Theorem 2  which may be useful for answering the question by tyobrien.

Prof. Fabio M. S. Lima